# VIM append a sequence of number at the end of each line

Tags: vim, append

I'm totally new to vim and I know what magical things vim can do. My requirement is to append a sequence of numbers at the end of each line and I saw somebody did that before in front of me. It's just that I don't have enough time to search for the correct command, so I think post a question here should be a faster way since I'm running out of time. Sorry for being a noob but seems this is the only way I can come up with.

So the sample file content is like

```
1       Afghanistan     
2       Albania 
3       Algeria 
4       American        
5       Andorra 
6       Angola  
7       Anguilla        
8       Antarctica
```

a list of countries, imagine it is a database table and each column is separated with tab. I already figured out a way to append tab to the end of each line, but now the problem is to add a number at the end of each line as well, and the number for each line is exactly same with its id(the first number)

I somehow think that it should be done with visual mode, but please tell me a working solution if you know. Any help is highly appreciated.

Best Regards,
Hai Lang

Answer (score 9):

Open your file in vim. Press ESC if not in escape mode.

write this `:%s/$/\=line('.')/`

This will append the sequence of numbers at the end of each line. To add numbers in the begining do

`:%s/^/\=line('.')/`

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks very much and it will be even greater if you explain this command a little bit.

Comment: This does not actually copy the number, it just appends the vim-buffer's line number to the line

Comment: `:%s/a/b` <= Means replace pattern a with b at every line. % is to specify everyline. `:%s/a/b/g` <= Everyline everyplace wherever a is there replace with b. Now in `:%s/$/\=line('.')/` _a_ is _$_ and _b_ is _=line('.')_ . $ means end of line and ^ means start of line. They are not start and end characters of the line. They actually are something just before starting character and just after last character (before newline) respectively

Comment: Indeed. This will not work if the IDs do not match the line numbers.

Answer (score 5):

Input:

```
1       Afghanistan     
2       Albania 
3       Algeria 
4       American        
5       Andorra 
6       Angola  
7       Anguilla        
8       Antarctica
```

Keystrokes:

```
:%s!^\(\d\+\).*!&\t\1<CR>
```

Output:

```
1       Afghanistan         1
2       Albania     2
3       Algeria     3
4       American            4
5       Andorra     5
6       Angola      6
7       Anguilla            7
8       Antarctica  8
```

[Par](http://vimgolf.com/) : 20

Explanation:

- `:` : [start the command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a)
- `%` : [on all lines](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%3a%)
- `s` : [subsititute](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#%3asubstitute)
- `!` : start of pattern
- `^` : start of line
- `\(` : [start of group](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/()
- `\d` : digit
- `\+` : [one or more](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/+)
- `\)` : end of group
- `.` : [any character](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/.)
- `*` : [any number of those](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/star)
- `!` : end of pattern
- `&` : replace with - [whole pattern](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#&)
- `\t` : a tab
- `\1` : first matched group
- <kbd>Carriage-return</kbd> : [execute](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#%3CCR%3E)

Comment: +1 for breakdown. May I suggest using the simpler `\t` escape rather than the un-SO-friendly `<C-v><C-i>` which will also not work for Win32 users out of the box?

Comment: Thanks, this works as well. And especial thanks to your explanation.

Comment: @sehe: Thanks. Have updated answer with your suggestion (I'm not a Windows programmer).

Answer (score 0):

You could use recordings, which are enabled by q followed by a letter, which is the bookmark for that recording.

E.g.
In normal mode go to the first line and type:

```
qe
^
y<space>
$
p
q (to end the recording)
```

Now type `@e` to play the recording from letter e or `20@e`, which repeats @e 20 times.
You can play around with the recordings like this. Maybe also record a `j`, in normal mode so it takes you to the next line.

Comment: Good suggestion, but `^ y $ p q` does not do what the OP wants.

Comment: To yank 1 character, `yl`. To yank the number, `yiw`.